# Is there any android library to play animations from After Effects json or aepx file

Tags: after-effects, android

I have created videos using After Effects. I want to export this file and replace photos with user uploaded. Is there any Android library that allows me to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this is more of a software development question than a video production question. It is borderline on topic and I suspect you probably won't get good answers.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nooooo.